# iOS 11.3.1 Iframe scroll issue in Safari browser with Ext JS modern 6.5.3

Tags: iphone, iframe, scroll, extjs6-modern, extjs6.5

I am having an issue in scrolling the iframe embedded website content in latest IOS 11.3.1(iPhone) Safari browser for mobile for Ext JS 6.5.3 modern
Following is the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2gli&view/editor).

Can anyone suggest the solution on it.

Comment: what is you exact problem *issue in scrolling* ?

Comment: page is stucked and i don't see any further scrolling for a page.. this issue is occurred after latest update of IOS to 11.3.1, in previous version it was fine.

Comment: Do anyone found the solution yet ?

Comment: have you checked with 11.3 ?

Comment: yes, but there it does'nt work.

Comment: I have also checked in my phone it's working fine after content load.

Comment: okay, please let me know  which version of iphone are you using?

Comment: I have checked in iOS 11.3 version

Comment: did you check on safari browser too ?

Comment: Yes I have checked in safari  browser too